# Which adventure game of a female with blonde hair is this?

Tags: game-identification

I have found this screenshot from an online site where they talked about adventure gaming. Does anyone know what game is this? They used the screenshot as a header and I thought it looks nice.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This is the action-adventure game [X-Blades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Blades) developed by Gaijin Entertainment. It was originally called Oniblade.

A kind of remake of the game is Blades of Times which has improved graphics, controls and a similar story.

Comment: The picture itself looks like it was taken from the developers web site: http://gaijin.ru/en/games/xblades

Comment: Blades of Time is a wholly unique game from X-Blades, it has no content from the original game.  This screenshot is from X-Blades.

Comment: Updated the answer to make it clearer what Blades of Time is.

Comment: Correct.  However, recommend to the OP not to waste their money, it's kind of a crap game with an interesting mechanic implemented badly.